# Angular SyncFusion's EJS-GRID Child Grid (Hierarchical Binding)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, syncfusion

I'm working on ejs-grid and I want to toggle(Expand/Collapse) a **child grid** when I click on a row in the grid.

I was able to get the row click functionality working using (rowSelected) attribute but I don't really know how to get the **current state** of a child grid(collapsed or expanded).

My Current Code

```html
toggleChildGrid(event){
    const rowIndex = event.rowIndex;
    const isCollapsed = true;
    if(isCollapsed){
        this.grid.detailRowModule.expand(rowIndex);
    }
    else{
        this.grid.detailRowModule.collapse(rowIndex)
    }
}
```

I just made the **isCollapsed** variable true but I will like that to be derived dynamically based on the state of the child grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set containing row indices that are expanded, and add/remove from that list to represent if the row is expanded/collapsed

```
private expandedRowIndices = new Set<number>();

toggleChildGrid(event: {rowIndex: number}): void {
    const rowIndex = { event };
    const isExpanded = this.expandedRowIndices.has(rowIndex);

    // If it is currently expanded, now collapse
    if (isExpanded) {
        this.grid.detailRowModule.collapse(rowIndex);
        this.this.expandedRowIndices.remove(rowIndex);
    } else {
        this.grid.detailRowModule.expand(rowIndex);
        this.this.expandedRowIndices.add(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the solutions work to an extent.
If the down-arrow or right-arrow icon is clicked, the expandedRowIndices doesn't update.

Comment: Could you attach the `add/remove` functionality to the click event handler for the down and right arrow?

Comment: I don't know how to do that plus the down & right arrow icon is automatically added when an ejs-grid has a childGrid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shared information we suspect that you want to expand/collapse the child grid based on the current state while clicking on the row of grid. To achieve your requirement we suggest you to use our default recordClick event.

Using this event we find the current state of child grid and based on that we have collapsed and expanded using expand and collapse method.

Please refer to the below code and sample link.

recordClick(args){
const isCollapsed = (args.target.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.classList.contains('e- detailrow') && (args.target.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.style.display != 'none')) == true ? true :  false;
if (!isCollapsed) {
this.grid.detailRowModule.expand(args.rowIndex);
}
else {
this.grid.detailRowModule.collapse(args.rowIndex);
}
}

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pm1ziu-9kpxum?file=app.component.ts

API Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid#recordclick

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
The solution works well but I noticed the last row doesn't work sometimes.